# How change tableview section header size dynamically in ios 11 using swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

i am creating an expandable tableview. i have added section and row for every section. created a xib file for styling sections and it works right in iphone 5s.but when i switch to iphone 8s my sections remain size of iphone 5s and width don't change to tableview. i have set constraint and some of my codes are as below:
[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            self.homeMenuTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0196, green: 0.1059, blue: 0.1647, alpha: 1.0)
            let px = 1 / UIScreen.main.scale
            let frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: self.homeMenuTableView.frame.size.width,height: px)
            let line = UIView(frame: frame)
            self.homeMenuTableView.tableHeaderView = line
            line.backgroundColor = self.homeMenuTableView.separatorColor
            homeMenuTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
            homeMenuTableView.dataSource=self
            homeMenuTableView.delegate=self
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = ExpandableHeaderView()
    header.customInit(title: sections[section].menuCellLabel, section: section, delegate: self)
    return header
}

func customInit(title: String, section: Int, delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate) {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MenuTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MenuTableViewCell
            let menucell = DataService.instance.getMenuCells()[section]
            cell.updateViews(menuCell: menucell)
    self.addSubview(cell)
    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate
}
```

Comment: You might need to share how you've set up the xib for people to be able to help. It would look like the width is not set as expandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading cell from xib but you are not assigning frame to it. due to which it takes width of cell in XIB

```
func customInit(title: String, section: Int, delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate) {
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MenuTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MenuTableViewCell
                let menucell = DataService.instance.getMenuCells()[section]
                cell.updateViews(menuCell: menucell)
    //Add this line in your code width issue will resolve
    cell.frame.size.width = tableView.frame.width

        self.addSubview(cell)
        self.section = section
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
```